# Activity with singleInstance launchMode and a new Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I'm a bit confused really. When it says that

Activities with **singleInstance** launchmode uses the singleton pattern, and that instance will be the root activity of a **new task**

When it says **new task**, does it mean that the launching activity will get executed in a new **thread???** Or the android system just uses **flags** to control activities navigation internally with datastructures within the **Main Thread**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Activities with singleInstance launchmode uses the singleton pattern

This is misleading. Activities, whatever the launchmode, should *never* be considered singletons. True, there is only one instance of the Activity when using `singleInstance`, but the normal Activity lifecycle still occurs and it is not safe to keep a static reference to any Activity.

> When it says new task, does it mean that the launching activity will get executed in a new thread???

No, all Activities live in the main thread and you should only interact with them there. The confusion comes from the usage of the word `task`, which does not refer to threading in this case. It refers to a group of Activities. There's a [useful reference concerning this subject](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) in the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

> does it mean that the launching activity will get executed in a new thread???

No it does not.

All app's activities (and services and receiver) are **executed on a single thread** called the main thread.

You can find a good read on the Android threading model [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)